# XOR all bytes in 64 bit register in fewer instructions

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, nasm, x86-64, micro-optimization

Assume on some x86-64 platform we have some 64-bit value stored in some 64-bit register (let it be the *RAX*). The challange is to *XOR* all bytes of initial value in fewer instruction calls (it doesn't matter where to store result). Here is my 8-instruction solution (in NASM):

```
mov    rbx, rax
bswap  rbx
xor    eax, ebx
mov    ebx, eax
bswap  ebx
xor    ax, bx
mov    bx, ax
xor    al, bh
```

I'm not very experienced in ASM programming, so maybe you guys have some better solution in term of instructions amount.
Thanks!

Comment: `xchg   bx` isn't even valid. Also, you can `xor al, ah`.

Comment: Do you really care about number of instructions, rather than number of uops on some CPU, or some other performance effect, or machine-code size?

Comment: @Jester, my fault. I fixed it, thx.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's a kind of challenge, not a real deal :)

Comment: you can replace `mov ebx, eax; bswap ebx` with `movbe ebx, eax`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
        movq xmm0,rax
        pclmullqlqdq xmm0,[mask]
        pextrb eax,xmm0,7


mask    dq 0101010101010101h, 0
```

This uses the carry-less multiplication [`pclmullqlqdq`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCLMULQDQ.html) to do all the xors in one instruction.  The last instruction extracts the accumulated result and stores it into `al`.

Comment: You could use `pextrb` at the end

Comment: I don't think it has an reg8 form though (even though its memory-dst form is m8)

Comment: @harold Weird.  The [manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRB:PEXTRD:PEXTRQ.html) says `r/m8` but the assembler doesn't accept an `r8`.

Comment: 3 instructions, nice... you win, but code-size I'm at ~half of yours. :)

Comment: @Ped7g It would be only two if I took more liberty with “it doesn't matter where to store result.”

Comment: You two extra `l`s in the mnemonic.  It's `pclmulqdq`.  And note that it's not baseline for x86-64; it has its own feature bit.  And of course `pextrb` is SSE4.1.  CPUs with SSE4.1 will normally have PCLMUL as well.  Probably a good idea to mention in the answer that this has restrictions, even though CPUs without those features are becoming rarer all the time as old machines are retired.

Comment: @PeterCordes `pclmullqlqdq` is an alias for `pclmulqdq xmm,xmm/m,0x00`.  Confer the manual I linked for detailed.

Answer (score 3):

This is supporting System V x86_64 ABI (i.e. directly callable from C/C++ in 64b linux, etc), 5 instructions (16 bytes) (`ret` excluded).

```
; input: rdi = 8x packed byte, output al = xorred value
xorAllRdiBytes:
    shld    rax, rdi, 32
    xor     eax, edi
    shld    edi, eax, 16
    xor     ax, di
    xor     al, ah
    ret
```

And that `xor ax,di` can be instead `xor eax, edi` to get 15B long version, but I will keep "ax, di" in first variant to make it more obvious what is it doing.

Probably a bit faster (according to Peter Cordes, and I believe him :)) (but with longer machine code and BMI2 instructions supported only on Intel Haswell+ CPUs and AMD Excavator (2015)) variant (also using the 32b xor in end):

```
; input: rdi = 8x packed byte, output al = xorred value
xorAllRdiBytes:
    rorx    rax, rdi, 32
    xor     eax, edi
    rorx    edi, eax, 16
    xor     eax, edi
    xor     al, ah
    ret
```

(the first variant is using only 80386 instructions, so any x86_64 CPU will run that one)

I guess the fuz's 3 (2) instructions one is probably a tiny bit faster, so unless you are optimizing on code size, or you don't have SSE4.1, this is still only second solution.

Comment: Use `rorx rax, rdi, r2` to copy-and-rotate without a false dependency on the old value of `rax`.